# Why does Spring boot returns 404 error, but works if I place all methods of all controllers under one controller class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I get 404 error when I try to send a request to access `handleFileUpload( )` method 
But if I place `handleFileUpload( )` in `DetailsController.java` things work. Why is that? I'm using Spring boot. 
I have two controller classes. 
I don't have ServletInitializer.java

com.amazon.s3
 |__ `AmazonS3Controller.java`
com.myproject
 |__ `DetailsController.java`

This is how my @SpringBootApplication class looks like

```
@SpringBootApplication //This annotation means, it is the starting point of the app. 
public class QqdApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QqdApplication.class, args);
}
```

DetailsController.java

```
@RestController
@Component
public class DetailsController {

    @Autowired
    private DetailsService detailsService;

   @RequestMapping("/contactUs")
    public ModelAndView contactUs(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("contactUs");
        return mav;
    }    
}
```

AmazonS3Controller.java

```
package com.amazon.s3;

import com.amazon.s3.AmazonS3Template;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/s")
public class AmazonS3Controller {

    private AmazonS3Template amazonS3Template;
    private String bucketName;

    @Autowired
    public AmazonS3Controller(AmazonS3Template amazonS3Template, @Value("${amazon.s3.default-bucket}") String bucketName) {
        this.amazonS3Template = amazonS3Template;
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
    }

  @PostMapping(value = "upload",  headers = "Accept=*/*")
  @ResponseBody
  public String handleFileUpload() {
      JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
      try {

  //      System.out.println("we ar ehere" + file.getName() + " " + file.getContentType() + " " + file.getSize());
        result.put("link", "https://static.swappa.com/static/icons/stars/star-on-small-green.png");
        System.out.println("imgae returned");
      } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      return new JSONArray().put(result).toString();    
  }
}
```

My `application.properties` looks like

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

#AWS details
amazon.s3.default-bucket=<someVal>

#Database
spring.datasource.....=....

#Hibernate
entitymanager.packagesToScan:com
spring.jpa.....=....
```

PS: Ok, After renaming the com.amazon.s3 to com.myproject.s3 things are working. But, I still don't get why it wasn't working before and why its working now.

P.S.S: I typed the above three lines here rather than comment, because SOF keep on telling me that there was too much code and less text. Sorry I cannot write stories here. I feel I gave enough details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@SpringBootApplication` includes `@ComponentScan`:

> The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using
>   @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan with their
>   default attributes:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

`@ComponentScan` will, by default, scan for annotations from the package of the class the annotation is residing on ( i.e. the package of `QqdApplication`)

> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the
>   package of the class that declares this annotation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

So the `@PostMapping` annotation was not being captured when placed in a controller in the package `com.amazon.s3 to com.myproject.s3`. Either you had to change the package to be under a scanned location, or you had to specify which packages to scan in the `@ComponentScan` annotation.